# Node.js is spawning more that one process and I am not sure why (Windows)

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I am having trouble with getting my node.js Discord Bot (Discord.js Lib) to run only one process.

#### How I am starting the script

dependencies :

```
ansi-colors 3.2.4
discord.js 11.4.2
enmap 4.8.4
esm 3.2.22
nodemon 1.18.11
superagent 5.0.2
uuid 3.3.2
```

devDependencies :

```
babel-eslint 10.0.1
eslint-config-airbnb-base 13.1.0
eslint-plugin-import 2.17.2
```

my `scripts` property of the `package.json` file

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon -r esm index.js"
  }
}
```

note : [`esm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) is a node module for running es6 modules

In `index.js` :

```js
/**
 * my real index.js file has a command handler,
 * error handler and much more, as well as a few
 * Enmaps for some personal uses, but nothing that
 * would make this bot reply to itself
 */

import Enmap from 'enmap';
import { Client } from 'discord.js';
import { config } from 'dotenv';

config();

const client = new Client({ disableEveryone: true });
client.commands = new Enmap

client.on('ready', client => {
  console.log('Ready!');
}

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot) {
    return;
  }

  /** @type {string} */
  const prefix = "-";

  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
    return;
  }

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/\s+/g);
  const command = args.shift();

  const cmd = client.commands.get(command);

  if (!cmd) {
    return;
  }

  cmd.run(message, args);
}

client.login(process.env.CLIENT_TOKEN)
```

In my directory with my `package.json`

```sh
$ npm start
```

It seems to start fine, but then 2, 3 or even 6 node processes show up in task manager and my program is responding that amount of times.

If there are 3 processes and I fire an event, it get triggered 3 times, even though I do not know what would be causing this.

Theoretically, only one 'message' event should be triggered

#### What I have tried

1. Killing all node.js processes in my current and other open terminals (Git Bash)
2. Killing all the processes in my Task Manager
3. Running my start script without calling npm
4. Running my start script (with and w/o npm) in the default command prompt

Comment: What is the code in index.js doing?  Is it starting a clustered server?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have clarified in my post